# How to implement AngularJS palette color picker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, color-picker

I want to implement palette color picker in Angularjs. Let me know Is there any angularJs library exits. OR How we can implement same like below image?

Thank.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that things. But It wants to implement same like above. I did some R&D but unable to find.

Comment: Implementing a color picker like the above would be too broad of a question. Stack Overflow exists to help people implement things like this, yes, but we are not a code-writing service. If you can [edit] your question to include your attempt at implementing such a control, I'm sure there are people who can help you with individual aspects of the creation.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need a library if you want to use `input type='color'`

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <input type="color" ng-model="vm.color" /><br/>
    Selected color: {{vm.color}}
</body>
```